# How to return character at a specific index?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to write a function that takes in an array and a string. The function needs to use the array method .indexOf and find the index of the passed-in string in the array. Then it needs to use the method .charAt to find the character at that index in the string and return that character. I'm pretty confused by this and not sure exactly what I need to do. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here is what I am trying:

```
cipherize = (arr, str) => {
  let index = arr.indexOf(str)
  return str.charAt(0)
}
```

It has to pass these tests:

```
should return "l" when called as cipherize(["books", "computers", "paper", "tablets"], "tablets")
should return "" when called as cipherize(["blue", "green", "yellow", "purple", "red"], "red")
```

Comment: The `.charAt()` method takes an integer index as its argument.

Comment: *"...to find the character at that index"*... ask yourself: which index?

Comment: @Pointy I have tried running `.charAt()` with an integer as its argument and my code still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Please provide the code in your question where you use the integer argument (update your question).

Comment: Try using the Javascript console and just playing around with charAt, e.g. "abcdef".charAt(3).

Comment: @trincot I use the integer argument in the same place. Is that wrong?

Comment: @DaveGoldberg I understand how to use `.charAt()` by itself. Putting in an integer as an argument to get back the character at that index you put as the argument. My confusion here is using the two methods together `.indexOf()` and `.charAt()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the `index` of the passed string to `charAt()`:

```js
cipherize = (arr, str) => {
  let index = arr.indexOf(str)
  return str.charAt(index); //pass index here
}
console.log(cipherize(["books", "computers", "paper", "tablets"], "tablets"));

console.log(cipherize(["blue", "green", "yellow", "purple", "red"], "red"));
```

Comment: Could you please explain a little more why just passing `index` as the argument works for this?

Comment: @stoney_24, first the `index` is the position of the passed string in the array. Then `chatAt(index)` returns the character from that position of the string ..... hope it clears your question...

Answer (score 2):

**@Stoney**, just replace `0` with `index` and it will work.

```
> const cipherize = (arr, str) => {
...   let index = arr.indexOf(str)
...   return str.charAt(index)
... }
undefined
> cipherize(["books", "computers", "paper", "tablets"], "tablets");
'l'
>
> cipherize(["blue", "green", "yellow", "purple", "red"], "red")
''
>
```